# Angular 2 Provider exception

Tags: angular, angular2-providers

When injecting service into component, I'm seeing the error:

> One or more of providers "CategoriesComponent" were not defined: [?, [object Object], BrowserXhr, [object Object], [object Object], XHRBackend, [object Object]].

Please help me to resolve this issue. Many thanks

Below is my code:

category.services.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';


import { Category } from './index';
// import * as global from '../shared/global/globals';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {
    private _baseUrl: string = '/api/v1/category/list';

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        // this._baseUrl = global.BASE_URL;
    }

    getCategories(): Observable<Category[]>{
        return this.http.get(this._baseUrl)
            .map((res: Response) => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
    var applicationError = error.headers.get('Application-Error');
    var serverError = error.json();
    var modelStateErrors: string = '';

    if (!serverError.type) {
      console.log(serverError);
      for (var key in serverError) {
        if (serverError[key])
          modelStateErrors += serverError[key] + '\n';
      }
    }

    modelStateErrors = modelStateErrors = '' ? null : modelStateErrors;

    return Observable.throw(applicationError || modelStateErrors || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

categories.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { Category, CategoryService } from './index';

@Component({
    // moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'categories',
    templateUrl: 'views/category/categories-component',
    providers: [CategoryService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {
    categories: Category[];

    isCollapsed = false;

    constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.categoryService.getCategories()
            .subscribe((categories: Category[]) => {
                this.categories = categories;
            }, 
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        // console.log('=======');
    }

    toggle(){
        this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed;
    }
}
```

navbar.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { CategoriesComponent } from '../../category/index';

@Component({
    // moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: 'views/navbar/navbar',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, CategoriesComponent]
})
export class NavbarComponent {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to provide services in your providers array ..... the error that occurs is due to this only...just change this in your categories.component.ts file :-

> providers: [CategoryService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]    to===> providers:
>   [HTTP_PROVIDERS]

this works if u have not provided it in your app component or main.ts file...

the second thing u need to change is the path of your categoryservice import as below :-

> import { CategoryService } from '.path to category.service'

it will work fine then :)

Comment: I've removed CategoriesService from providers but it show another error: Can't resolve all parameters for CategoriesComponent: (?).

Comment: I got it, the problem is I imported CategoryService from index.ts which is not allowed in angular 2

Comment: if u have not provided it in ur app.component file then don't remove it from ur providers array... just do the second thing as i mentioned above